# Should I use both no-webp and no-jpeg2000 for fallbacks on Modernizr?

Tags: image, modernizr, webp, jpeg2000

I'm unsure of whether I need to use both no-webp and no-jpeg2000, like this:

```
.no-webp .no-jpeg2000 .coverart.pli {
    background-image: url('../img/coupe.jpg');
}
```

or if it is sufficient to only use one as a fallback, i.e.:

```
.no-webp .coverart.pli {
    background-image: url('../img/coupe.jpg');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr sometimes doesn't work.
That's why I prefer this way:

```
.coverart.pli {
    background-image: url('../img/coupe.jpg');
}

.webp .coverart.pli {
    background-image: url('../img/coupe.webp');
}
```